# celery: print the status of each task within a group started with apply_async

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am trying to print the status of 4 remote tasks, obaining info from each AsyncResult within the group.

So far I am able to print the status, but not the name of the task that produced (or has yet to produce) the AsyncResult (see console print below)

Another problem I am having is that although the group is launched with apply_async(expires=30), there is no expiry, as long as there is one sub task "PENDING", the loop goes on forever.

```
from celery import group

ping_results = group(
    ping_portal.s(),
    ping_factory.s(),
    ping_factory_m.s(),
    ping_proxy.s()
).apply_async(expires=30)

while ping_results.waiting():

    c = ping_results.completed_count()

    print("{0} nodes have responded".format(c))

    for c in ping_results.children:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(c, c.status))
```

Console:

```
3 nodes have responded
33cae071-8944-4a56-9cc1-d0c83bfb0a20: PENDING
97f9a481-8d31-4889-9ea2-6f43d7561443: SUCCESS
8f030dfe-e235-4794-8a84-bf583992528a: SUCCESS
b971a4ac-d23f-4378-b8b6-2c55f3d05618: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

As `children` attribute of [`GroupResult`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/result.html#GroupResult) is just a sequence of `AsyncResult` instances, it should be able to obtain the task name by the `name` attribute of the result, e.g. in your case something like

```
for c in ping_results.children:
    print("{0}[{1}]: {2}".format(c.name, c, c.status))
```